# api.crossref.org port 443: Connection refused

Tags: r, api

I'm relatively new to working with API's in R and I'm currently working with the rcrossref package to match DOI's of scientific papers with the names of the authors. I have a dataframe with DOI's in a column (~13.000 rows) that I want to enrich with multiple columns in which the names of the researchers are listed. My current code looks like this:

```
df <- cr_works(dois = DOI_researchers$DOI, .progress = "time") %>%
pluck("data") %>%
 unnest(author)
```

The code seems to be working, but after a few seconds I get the following error:

```
in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : 
Failed to connect to api.crossref.org port 443: Connection refused
```

When I use a small sample of my dataset, the code seems to be working. But when it takes more than approximately 1 minute to run the code I get said error.

Am I doing something wrong in the request I am sending out to the API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interestingly, I tried connecting to api.crossref.org port 443 when I saw your question and was unable. Then a few seconds later the connection succeeded. It might just be a temporary or intermittent issue. Also interesting, the server only seems to wait 2 or 3 seconds for an HTTP request before closing the connection, so if you're running in a debugger or doing some extended calculation after connecting you might have trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Interestingly, the behaviour of when the process gets killed also seems to differ. I've ran the scripts multiple times now and in a few instances the process got killed after ~15 minutes rather than seconds. So is it best to try running it a different time? Or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know.

Comment: Do you know if api.crossref has connection-throttling? Are you a "paid" user or is this an open api? You might try slowing down (throttling) your own connections. (I know nothing about them either, so I'm just making guesses here.)

Comment: The crossref API is indeed free. There is something called the 'polite pool' which I am registered to. There are some API limits, being: x-rate-limit-limit: 50
and x-rate-limit-interval: 1s. Could this be part of the problem?